# NVDA doesn't read link or title attribute in Navigation in Firefox, or screen reader text

Tags: html, wordpress, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I am trying to make the website time-realty.com ADA compliant. It is built using WordPress with the Customizr theme.  I am using NVDA reader to check that the navigation makes sense.

In Firefox,on mouse-over, NVDA reader just says the name of the page "Contact us," but in Internet Edge it says "Contact Us" then reads the entire URL https...slash and followed by the Title Attribute.

I need it to work for mouseover as many local real estate agencies and individuals have been receiving letters from an attorney that specifically says there is a problem with the navigation and that problem is: "When the indicator (mouse) accesses the area where the text is the screen reader only reads the text."

The link looks like this:
`<a title="Go to our contact us page" href="https://www.time-realty.com/time-realty-services/location/">Contact Us</a>`

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you copy word for word what was said as there is nothing wrong with that hyperlink it is expected behaviour when using the mouse to hover links, just because one browser/screen reader combination announces more does not automatically mean you have done anything wrong (which you haven't). Don't get me wrong there are loads of accessibility issues with the site (colour contrast of orange text too low, menu should have `aria-expanded`, circular images on homepage need `alt` attributes, especially as they are hyperlinks (and so are empty hyperlinks) etc. etc. but this one point is a non issue

Comment: Sure, I've made some progress using the special class "screen-reader-text" which uses clip to make text only for screen readers. Now, in Firefox, it says "link" after each menu item. In Chrome, however, just says "About Time" when you hover the mouse over the "About Time" link.  It doesn't say link and it doesn't read the URL. I'm installing the new Internet Edge and we will see how that one works.

Comment: You are wasting your time and probably making accessibility works. **There is nothing wrong with what you have done** (Other than the fact that `title` isn't really useful on your links in this case but that is a usability issue not an ADA / WCAG one). That is why I asked you to say exactly what was said because if they are raising this as an issue they have no idea what they are on about. Using visually hidden text to say "link" does not improve accessibility, it makes it worse.

Comment: I agree, but when I'm fighting an attorney with a lot more money than me I have to do what they say or else... Thank you for the confirmation that it has been done correctly.